# What does the -p option do in the read command?

Tags: options, read

**What does the -p option do in the read command?**

An example:

> read -p "Please enter your first name: " firstName

An explanation of the -p option on [read's manual page](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html) (I don't understand this):

> output the string PROMPT without a trailing newline before attempting to read

I don't understand what 'the string PROMPT' means, nor do I understand what 'a trailing newline' is.

Comment: I don't understand what 'the string PROMPT' means, nor do I understand what 'a trailing newline' is, so I don't understand what -p does to the read command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand what 'the string PROMPT' means, nor do I understand what 'a trailing newline' is.

**Prompt** is how the string given after `-p` is called. User is presented with a prompt (`Please enter your first name:` and enters value that will be put in `firstName` variable.

Without **trailing newline** means that when user starts typing, the characters will appear on the screen (will be echoed to) right after `Please enter your first name:`in the same line (as opposed to appearing below the prompt).

Comment: And "trailing" means it is put on at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Running the example would show you.  The script will display

```
Please enter your first name:
```

and your terminal's cursor would be one space past the ":" (on the same line).  If you type anything, and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, the text is put into the shell variable `$firstName`

```
Please enter your first name: Kaiylar
```

sets the variable to "Kaiylar".  In the script you could type

```
echo $firstName
```

and see

```
Kaiylar
```

In the manual, *PROMPT* is a name for the string

```
"Please enter your first name: "
```

and newlines are the character ending the line of text and starting a *new line* of text.