# How to read input lines with newline characters from command line?

Tags: bash, shell, posix, input, read

I found this to get user input from the command line. But it is failing into recognizing the new line characters I put into the input. Doing:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -e -p "Multiline input=" variable;
printf "'variable=%s'" "${variable}";
```

1. Typing `'multi\nline'` on `Multiline input=` makes `printf` output `'variable=multinline'`
2. Typing `'multi\\nline'` on `Multiline input=` makes `printf` output `'variable=multi\nline'`

How `printf` can print the new line I read by `read -p`, i.e., output

`multi
line`

Instead of `multinline` or `multi\nline`?

Related questions:

1. [What does the -p option do in the read command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269798/what-does-the-p-option-do-in-the-read-command)
2. [bash: read: how to capture '\n' (newline) character?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383197/bash-read-how-to-capture-n-newline-character)
3. [shell: read: differentiate between EOF and newline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383184/shell-read-differentiate-between-eof-and-newline/383196#383196)
4. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296108/how-do-i-add-a-line-break-for-read-command
5. [Read arguments separated by newline](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483372/read-arguments-separated-by-newline)
6. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43190306/how-to-add-new-line-after-user-input-in-shell-scripting

Comment: This is why you should always use `-r` for the read command.

Comment: For reference: [What is the meaning of read -r ?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192786/what-is-the-meaning-of-read-r)

Comment: Type `help read` into your interactive shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If typing in `\n` (as in the two characters `\` and `n`) is acceptable, then you can use `printf` to interpret it:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS= read -rep "Multiline input=" variable;
printf -v variable "%b" "$variable"
printf "'variable=%s'\n" "${variable}";
```

For example:

```
~ ./foo.sh
Multiline input=foo\nbar
'variable=foo
bar'
```

From [the bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read):

> The backslash character ‘\’ may be used to remove any special meaning
>   for the next character read and for line continuation.

The "line continuation" bit seems to imply you can't escape newlines unless you use a different character as the line delimiter.

Comment: if already using `bash`, then instead of `printf %b ...` the OP could use just `variable=${variable//\\n/$'\n'}` (and unlike `printf -v`, this will also work in ksh and mksh).

Answer (score 1):

@muru has the right bash answer.

An alternative: let `printf` handle the backslash sequences, but you have to be careful about `%` characters in the input

```
read -r input
printf "${input//%/%%}\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using some feature of `bash` or `printf`, I used `sed` to replace the escaped newline character `\\n` by an actual new line:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
read -e -p -r "Multiline input=" variable;
printf "'variable=%s'" "${variable}";
variable=$(printf "${variable}" | sed 's/\\n/\n/g');
```

References:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065016/how-to-replace-n-string-with-a-new-line-in-unix-bash-script
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10748453/replace-comma-with-newline-in-sed-on-macos
4. [Can sed replace new line characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114943/can-sed-replace-new-line-characters)